Unable to query SVN log in Golang
I am trying to query the log of a file in SVN to see the latest commit and author. When I run the command via command line, it works:
/opt/homebrew/bin/svn --username XXXX --password XXXXX --non-interactive --trust-server-cert log -r 1:HEAD https://svnRepo.com/svn/SampleCode/AppCode/branches/Release_69.00/Batch1/Backend/arc/appEvents.jaa  --stop-on-copy -l 1

If I call the same via the GoLang os/exec:
func runSVNCommand(username, password string, outputNeeded bool, dir string, args ...string) (string, error) {
    cmdArgs := append([]string{"--username", username, "--password", password, "--non-interactive", "--trust-server-cert"}, args...)
    cmd := exec.Command("svn", cmdArgs...)
    if dir != "" {
        cmd.Dir = dir
    }
    // cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    fmt.Println("SVN Command being executed: ", cmd.String())
    if outputNeeded {
        output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()

        if err != nil {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("error running svn command: %v\nOutput: %s", err, output)
        }
        return string(output), nil
    } else {
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    }
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return "", err
}

it gives me this error:

Output: svn: E160013: File not found: revision 680933, path 'AppCode/branches/Release_69.00/Batch1/Backend/arc/appEvents.jaa  --stop-on-copy'


'AppCode/branches/Release_69.00/Batch1/Backend/arc/appEvents.jaa --stop-on-copy' <--- this whole thing is treated as a file name.
